# Cantango : Permits vs Permissions, when to use each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

What are the pros and cons of using the Permit engine instead of the Permission engine in Rails' Cantango (and vice versa) ?

Which is better for performance ? What is allowed by one and not by the other ?

Is it better to disable one when using the other (like for perf concerns) or should they be used in complement to one another ?